# How to find local trends on Twitter for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I think we can all agree that the "# Discover" button in the official Twitter for iPhone app is a big waste of screen space. I never really rely on Twitter to "Discover" anything other than that which is said by those who I follow. But if there was one thing I did want to discover, it would be local trends. Is there any way to access this information in Twitter for iPhone? Is there another app that better serves this information?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the Twitter App uses location services for Trends. Is that enabled on your phone? Like you, I don't use the #Discover page often because it is just not relevant to me.

Comment: Location services are on yet trends seem to be national, at best (There's currently a "Rooney" in there). Where can I see NYC trends?